# A question related to a signed measure on the real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am currently working on the following problem from a past qualifying exam.

> Let $\nu$ be a finite signed measure on $\mathbb{R}.$ Define a function $$g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\:d\nu:=\int \chi_{(-\infty, x]\:d\nu}$$
> where $\chi$ is the characteristic function.

> (1) Prove that $g$ is right-continuous. That is
> $$\lim_{h\searrow 0}g(x+h)=g(x)$$
> for all $x\in \mathbb{R}.$

> (2) Consider the Radon-Nikodym decomposition of $\nu=fm+\mu,$ where $m$ is the Lebsegue measure, $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, and $v\perp m.$ Prove that $g$ is differentiable at almost all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $g'(x)=f(x),m\text{-a.e. }x$

I am completely stuck on this problem and don't know how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1), one needs to use the upper-continuity of measures. Since $g(x) = \nu((-\infty, x])$ any sequence $h_n$ with $h_n \searrow x$ obeys
$$(-\infty, x] = \bigcap_{n\geq 1} (-\infty, x + h_n],$$
and $(-\infty, h_{n+1}] \subset (-\infty, h_n]$ for all $n\geq 1$. Thus $|\nu| < \infty$ implies that
$$\nu((-\infty, x]) = \nu\left(\bigcap_{n\geq 1}(-\infty, x + h_n]\right) =  \lim_{n\to \infty} \nu((-\infty, h_n]),$$
and as $h_n$ was any sequence decreasing to $x$ part (1) follows.

For (2), note that
$$\frac{g(x+h/2) - g(x-h/2)}{h} = \frac{\nu((x-h/2, x+h/2])}{h} = \frac{\nu((x-h/2, x+h/2])}{m((x-h/2, x+h/2])}.$$
The family of intervals $\{(x-h/2, x+h/2]\}$ shrinks nicely to $x$ as $h\searrow 0$, so we can use the well-known theorem (see, for example, Folland's Real Analysis 2nd ed, Theorem 3.22) that
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\nu((x-h/2, x+h/2])}{m((x-h/2, x+h/2])} = f(x)$$
for $m$-almost every $x\in \mathbb R^n$. A similar argument shows the same thing if $h\nearrow 0$. But this is equivalent to asserting that $g'$ exists $m$-a.e., and that $g' = f$ $m$-a.e.

Comment: It is againts the rules of MSE to answer questions without context. Please read: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

Comment: @geetha290krm I was not aware of this rule, it appears I cannot take down my answer as it has been accepted. I'll avoid doing this in the future.